# Use a json file as Ansible input to dynamically update inventory file

Tags: ansible, terraform, devops, circleci, ansible-inventory

I am new to the Ansible technology that I would like to use in addition to Terraform.
I deploy servers with Terraform which generates after deployment a json file with all the outputs.
This file looks like this:

`cat terraform-outputs.json`

```
{
  "port": {
    "sensitive": false,
    "type": "string",
    "value": "9200"
  },
  "environment": {
    "sensitive": false,
    "type": "string",
    "value": "uat"
  },
  "private_ip": {
    "sensitive": false,
    "type": "string",
    "value": "10.132.0.3"
  },
  "public_ip": {
    "sensitive": false,
    "type": "string",
    "value": "34.79.32.71"
  }
}
```

I can then update my playbook file by parsing this json file using the lookup file feature of Ansible.

`cat playbook.yml`

```
- name: Write outputs port var
  hosts: web
  vars:
    tfOutputs: "{{ lookup('file', 'terraform-outputs.json') }}"

  tasks:
    - name: "Print"
      debug:
        msg: "{{ tfOutputs.port.value }}"
```

Before launching my command `ansible-playbook -i hosts.ini playbook.yml` I would like to update my Ansible inventory file (`hosts.ini`) so that it includes the public IP address in my group [web] by retrieving it from my Terraform outputs json file.

`cat hosts.ini`

```
[web]
                  ; <-- Dynamically adds public IP "34.79.32.71" here

[web:vars]
ansible_ssh_user=user
ansible_ssh_private_key_file=~/.ssh/elastic-uat
```

**NB** : I don't want to use Terraform's "template_file" resource to best decouple my Terraform job from my Ansible job launched by my CircleCI deployment chain.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: I'm not answering your question directly, because there's an easier way with Ansible to target EC2 hosts. Use the aws_ec2 collection. Then you will be able to target your hosts based on tags, vpc_id, etc: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/amazon/aws/aws_ec2_inventory.html

Comment: Thanks @paulg, I work on multi cloud environments (GCP + OVH). Is it relevant to use the Ansible collections when all the information I need is gathered in the Terraform outputs?

Comment: Valid point. On my Mac I would use a bash script to update the hosts dynamically. Not sure how to achieve the same on a windows OS with Ansible. What OS is your Ansible installed on?

Comment: I work locally on Mac. I also run the same deployment (Terraform + Ansible) with CircleCI

Comment: In terms of decoupling, using a Terraform rendered template for the inventory would be no different than your current path with a JSON of TF outputs. Either way, this would be easier to manipulate if your inventory was YAML or JSON. Could you go that route?

Comment: I confirm @paulg's proposition.
In my case (multi provider... GCP + OVH) the [gcp_compute plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/google/cloud/gcp_compute_inventory.html#ansible-collections-google-cloud-gcp-compute-inventory) is an official solution which should partly be able to answer my problem... There does not seem to be a plugin for OVH yet

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your `terraform-outputs.json` file has captured the result of running `terraform output -json`, and thus contains the values and types of all of your output values at once.

Extracting just the IP address from there would require some sort of glue scripting. Solving it using shell scripts would entail using a tool like [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to select just `.public_ip.value` from that.

You mentioned that you want to keep your Terraform configuration decoupled from Ansible, which is a laudable goal, but I'm not sure if you'd consider the automation that's *running* Terraform to be subject to that requirement too. If not, you might be able to simplify the glue scripting by asking Terraform to extract just the single value you want:

```
terraform output -raw public_ip
```

This should print out just `34.79.32.71`, which is likely easier to template into your `hosts.ini` file using some glue scripting, since it avoids any need for the glue script to parse JSON.